# NullPointerException on Scala reflection with typeOf[T]

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I am trying to process something from given type in Scala generics like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit private val tag: TypeTag[T] = typeTag[T]
private def getTypeString(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): String = typeOf[T] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OvalTest] => "tests"
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OvalObject]=> "objects"
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OvalState]=> "states"
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OvalVariable] => "variables"
}
```

I am getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.typeOf(TypeTags.scala:357)
    at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.typeOf$(TypeTags.scala:357)
    at scala.reflect.api.Universe.typeOf(Universe.scala:73)
    at composer.OvalIndexer$ElementsIndexer.getTypeString(OvalIndexer.scala:142)
    at composer.OvalIndexer$ElementsIndexer.<init>(OvalIndexer.scala:148)
    at composer.OvalIndexer$.createIndex(OvalIndexer.scala:48)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:11)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Null Pointer happens on line `private val ovalType = getTypeString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have this line?

```
implicit private val tag: TypeTag[T] = typeTag[T]
```

It isn't clear what `T` is in this scope, but the result will be that `tag` is `null` because `typeTag[T]` sees there is an implicit `tag: TypeTag[T]` available and returns it. Except it isn't initialized yet so it'll see `null`. Then if `typeOf[T]` is used with the same `T`, it'll get `null` as its implicit argument resulting in the exception you see.

```
private val ovalType = getTypeString
```

Without a type parameter it probably infers `getTypeString[Nothing]`. Is that what you want?